# Excel VBA, add hyperlink attached to comment's shape object

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm wondering why the following code doesn't work:

```
Dim shp as Shape
With Range("D7")
    .AddComment
    .Comment.Visible = True
    Set shp = .Comment.Shape
End With
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=shp, Address:="", _
                   SubAddress:="A7", ScreenTip:="Move"
```

If I do the similar thing with a newly created Shape object (for example, rectangle), it works, but as far as I set an Anchor to comment's Shape, code fails with

```
Run-time error '5':
Invalid procedure call or argument
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Ahpe? You mean shape?

Comment: Sorry for mistyping, of course, shape :)

Comment: Which line is raising the error?

Comment: The last one, with the call to hyperlinks.add

Comment: Hm, [subranges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490(v=office.14).aspx) were introduced with Excel 2010 so I can't test it at work with 2007. But what I see is, that Address is required and you give him a nullstring. Is this valid?

Comment: The same result is if I replcae the last call with something like Add Anchor:=shp,Address:="http://www.google.com" , ScreenTip:="Google", the subaddress was used for simplicity only. Btw, nullstring is valid, the code I posted just moves the selection to "A7" and works well with other shape objects.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010, standard edition

Answer (score 2):

The comment is a type of shape, but it doesn't support all shape properties - including hyperlinks, unfortunately. That's why you're able to add a hyperlink to your other shape, but not to the comment.

A comment doesn't usually let you click on it. Since you've changed the visible property to true, this changes the default behavior making the comment stay on top of some surronding cells. Since this is happening, you're better off making a shape that *looks like* a comment, but really isn't. Hyperlink your comment-looking shape, and you've got the answer.

An easy alternative would be to link the cell to a hyperlink.

Comment: Thanks for an answer!  Linking a cell to hyperlink isn't a good solution for my situation - I'm writing a macro for comparing data in 2 workbooks and marking differnces. The idea was to change format of marked cells and add comment with the value specified in another workbook, and add a hyperlink to comment to allow user quickly navigate to the context in another workbook. As the value in the marked cell can be a hyperlink itself, adding hyperlink to the cell can be bad. So I'll try to imitate the comments with stadard shape. Thanks!

Comment: Good deal. You've got several options, but I'd like to suggest one more. Excel works best with presenting information in a row-and-column worksheet format. With that in mind, another option might be to mark differences between the 2 workbooks in a worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've noticed is that if you enter in just a URL to a comment during creation then when the comment is displayed on screen via "Show comment" it will be clickable and will lead you to the URL in question. Even after editing the text in the comment it will continue to work as a hyperlink.

This is therefore a workaround for enabling a comment to link to at most one URL.